# How do I center the Caret position of a JTextPane by autoscrolling?

Tags: java, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I would like to auto scroll in my JTextPane so that the line with the caret (which is highlighted) is centered.
I am highlighting the line by using the Utilities.getRow(...caretPosition) method.
Seems to be a pretty unknown problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Center Line in Scroll Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/04/center-line-in-scroll-pane/). It centers the caret vertically, but it is trivial to also center the caret horizontally.

Here is the code modified so it also centers horizontally:

```
public static void centerLineInScrollPane(JTextComponent component)
{
    Container container = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, component);

    if (container == null) return;

    try
    {
        Rectangle r = component.modelToView(component.getCaretPosition());
        JViewport viewport = (JViewport)container;

        int extentWidth = viewport.getExtentSize().width;
        int viewWidth = viewport.getViewSize().width;

        int x = Math.max(0, r.x - (extentWidth / 2));
        x = Math.min(x, viewWidth - extentWidth);

        int extentHeight = viewport.getExtentSize().height;
        int viewHeight = viewport.getViewSize().height;

        int y = Math.max(0, r.y - (extentHeight / 2));
        y = Math.min(y, viewHeight - extentHeight);

        viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(x, y));
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to make it scroll smoother, this seems pretty interrupting when reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i adjusted it:

```
int y = Math.max(0, r.y - (extentHeight / 2));
            y = Math.min(y, viewHeight - extentHeight);
            int oldY = viewport.getViewPosition().y;
            for(int i = oldY;i<y;i++){
            viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(0, i));
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
```